# Run multiple rake tasks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake

Is it possible to rewrite these four invocations to run at the same time?

```
Rake::Task["rake:task1"].invoke
Rake::Task["rake:task2"].invoke
Rake::Task["rake:task3"].invoke
Rake::Task["rake:task4"].invoke
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by running them *at the same time*?

Comment: i hope he/she means one after the other but only needing one call to trigger all 4

Answer (score 4):

Add this to the appropriate .rake file:

```
task :all => [:task1, :task2, :task3, :task4]
```